# How do I turn off Nintendo Game&Watch?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-game-and-watch

I have a Nintendo mini classics fire today and I have no idea how to turn it off! I've tried waiting 10 minutes but no change. If you guys can help that would be awesome.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_%26_Watch_games#Fire

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: have you tried holding the Game A or Game B button?

Comment: No luck RenaissanceProgrammer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can tell, they cannot be turned off. There is a section about battery life in the [Nintendo Wikia page](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Fire) about the fire that says:

> With the clock, the battery lasts an estimated 6 months with LR43
> batteries and 12 months with SR43 batteries. If the user plays the game
> only one hour a day, the system would last for six months on LR43 (battery
> life with SR43 is unknown). The user should notice when the battery's life
> has been depleted when the screen's display is hard to distinguish.

So it seems you just have to let it run out and replace the battery.

Answer (score 2):

Out of my own personal experience with a few Nintendo Watch/Game devices, there is no way to turn them off. I tried pressing different buttons, but nothing worked. It is fine though,(You wouldn't turn off a watch, would you?) They do last for a long time. The one I had lasted for more than 6 months, (although I did not use it much).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is take the batteries out. This will shut the device off.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Arqade. As much as your answer does give an answer that would work, you should probably watch your tone. the line and a half of dots were not necessary. Something like 'Taking the batteries out would turn off the console, and prevent battery loss' would have been perfectly correct.